# Problem with Show

Tags: plotting

I have the following code that generates two 3-D graphs. When I try to visualise the graphs together with Show command only the first one is shown. I interchanged the order but still it shows only the one I put first. Never faced such a problem with Show command. Could you please help?

```
LF7 = {2079.6965019978416`, 1803.4376474050528`, 1527.1615374986422`, 1250.856394855333`, 974.4966166565208`, 698.01423619156`, 421.1516664158343`};
galpha7 = {0.72`, 0.75`, 0.7826086956521738`, 0.8181818181818181`, 0.8571428571428572`, 0.9`, 0.9473684210526316`};
\[Gamma]alpha7 = {0.00316055625790139`, 0.0030341340075853347`, 0.0029077117572692793`, 0.0027812895069532235`, 0.002654867256637168`, 0.0025284450063211123`,   0.002402022756005057`};
lsta7 = Table [{galpha7[[i]], \[Gamma]alpha7[[i]], LF7[[i]]}, {i, 1, 7}];
Pa7 = ListLinePlot3D[lsta7, PlotStyle -> Directive[Cyan, Thick, Dashed], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"g", "\[Gamma]", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(L\)]\) (Hz)"},    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Cyan}, {"CC"}], PlotRange -> All];

LF8 = {4269.328602125276`, 3005.305274547868`, 2373.2787439520644`, 1741.2276891573697`, 1109.1092112454387`, 792.972778446509`, 476.64231508537097`};
galpha8 = {0.7346938775510204`, 0.8`, 0.8372093023255813`, 0.8780487804878049`, 0.9230769230769232`, 0.9473684210526316`, 0.9729729729729729`};
\[Gamma]alpha8 = {0.0046226415094339605`, 0.004245283018867924`, 0.004056603773584905`, 0.0038679245283018858`, 0.003679245283018867`, 0.003584905660377358`, 0.0034905660377358484`};
lsta8 = Table [{galpha8[[i]], \[Gamma]alpha8[[i]], LF8[[i]]}, {i, 1, 7}];
Pa8 = ListLinePlot3D[lsta8, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"g", "\[Gamma]", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(L\)]\) (Hz)"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Black}, {"CB"}], PlotRange -> All];

Show[Pa7, Pa8]
```

Comment: Use: `PlotRange -> All`

Comment: `Show` uses the `PlotRange` from the first `Graphics`, so as Daniel said, you need to specify `All`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!